# error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

After updating the packages "Xamarin.Forms" and "Xamarin.Forms.Maps" to latest version i.e "3.0.0.446417", the project will no longer build and I get this error:

```
    C:\Users\[MyUser]\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.446417\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets(35,3):
error MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be loaded from the assembly
C:\Users\[MyUser]\.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.446417\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

The error refers to this place of the file *Xamarin.Forms.Targets*:

```
<XamlGTask
    XamlFiles="@(EmbeddedResource)" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.xaml' AND '$(DefaultLanguageSourceExtension)' == '.cs'"
    Language = "$(Language)"
    AssemblyName = "$(AssemblyName)"
    OutputPath = "$(IntermediateOutputPath)">
    <Output ItemName="FilesWrite" TaskParameter="GeneratedCodeFiles" />
    <Output ItemName="Compile" TaskParameter="GeneratedCodeFiles" />
</XamlGTask>
```

And the XamlGTask is underlined with a warning which says:

```
Task 'XamlGTask' is not defined
```

What I've done so far is cleaning the whole solution, deleting the obj/bin folders and also clearing All Nuget Caches from Package Manager Settings but none of them helped.

Comment: Also try after  deleting Prefetch, temp and %temp% folders.

Comment: Unluckily that didn't work.

Comment: I won't make this an official answer as I have no idea why this worked. I just upgraded Xamarin.Forms via NUGET, and then it worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> error MSB4062: The “Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi” task could not be loaded from the assembly

To resolve this issue, you should definitely make sure **all projects reference the same version of the package Xamarin.Forms**.

In your `Solution Explorer` right click on your solution node and select `Manage NuGet Packages for solution...`. Select the `Consolidate` tab and click on the `Xamarin.Forms` NuGet package, confirm all projects used the same version. If not, update all to the same version.

Besides, some one said that install .NET Framework 4.7.1 would help solve this issue, you can check if it helps.

Certified: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/324869#Comment_324869

Note: If you could not install the .net framework 4.7.1 successfully, please try to update your Windows 10 to latest release. Thanks @Vahid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: All my projects had the same versions of packages i.e there aren't any packages listed in consolidate section. All my packages
I took the advice of @DanSiegel from here and downloaded .NETFramework 4.7.1 but as installation failed, after a further searching I had to update my Windows 10 to latest release and now I no longer get that error and my project builds successfully.

Comment: @Vahid, Thanks for your reply. I will add your comment to my answer, this can be beneficial to other community members who have the same issue(could not install .net framework 4.7.1). Thanks :).

Comment: my computer was already as up to date as it would let me. for me it was install .net framework 4.7.1 and a restart. it builds now.

Comment: I also had to ensure I was building against the right SDK. This is in the project under Application > Compile using Android Version, NOT Android Manifest. I made sure to set to build against the highest SDK. I also ensured all Xamarin.Forms NuGets were the same version - that's important, too!

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1:**

Sometimes it helps to kill MsBuild process with taskmanager. (Press ctrl+shift+Esc)

**Solution 2:**

Clean Solution

Close Visual Studio

Delete all obj/bin folders

(Sometimes a delete of packages folder is required)

Restart visual studio and rebuild

Comment: Solution 2 is all I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all the above and failed. I mention that I use VS2017 v15.7.5.

If nothing works try this:

- Close VS - all instances
- Reopen VS without loading your solution
- Go to Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> NuGet Package Manager -> General -> Clear All NuGet Cache(s)
- Load you solution and Build.

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS 2017 with Xamarin Forms. These are the steps I took to resolve this error:

1. Make sure you're running same version of Xamarin.Forms for both Android and iOS
2. Close Solution
3. Open VS -> Tools -> Options -> Nuget Package Manager -> Clear NuGet Caches
4. Open Solution in Windows Explorer
5. Shift Delete vs folder
6. Shift Delete bin & obj folders in Android and iOS
7. Restart Computer
8. Once restarted, open VS and let it restore NuGet packages automatically (this may take time)
9. Clean solution
10. Rebuild solution

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the solution was a pending restart for the windows update that had to be performed. very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue recently, the simplest solution is to install **.net framework 4.7.1**, that's it. It's because **4.7.1 is required for netstandard2!**

Reference: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2667

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

**Step 1: Close Visual Studio with the solution you are working on.**

**Step 2: Delete the .vs folder in your solution folder (The .vs folder is generally hidden)**

**Step 3: Re-open your solution with visual studio**

Thats it.