# Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTaskAbi

Tags: xamarin.forms

Hi I was having this problem for almost a week now, can anyone please help me about this, I was trying to create a xamarin.forms app but upon creating project this problem comes up it cant detect the nuget and sdk dependencies, thanks

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvzQg.png):

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249343/error-msb4062-the-xamarin-forms-build-tasks-gettasksabi-task-could-not-be-loa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249343/error-msb4062-the-xamarin-forms-build-tasks-gettasksabi-task-could-not-be-loa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamrain form build task reference error in visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51821450/xamrain-form-build-task-reference-error-in-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Is the .NET standard library in your SDK folder?

Comment: yes somehow it seems like it cant detect it, and it creates a bunch of errors on the project