# Xamrain form build task reference error in visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am using visual studio 2017 and when I install xamrain from build 3.0 then I get the error bellow running application. How to resolve this problem?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   D:\Practics\AndroidApp\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  AndroidApp.Android  D:\Practics\AndroidApp\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets   36
>        Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error     The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.GetTasksAbi" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly
>   D:\Practics\AndroidApp\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that
>   the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  AndroidApp  D:\Practics\AndroidApp\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.0.0.561731\build\netstandard1.0\Xamarin.Forms.targets   36

Comment: *"The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask"* Done with that?

Comment: Here is the error when i click error then go to this line of code <GetTasksAbi>
   <Output TaskParameter="AbiVersion" PropertyName="_XFTasksAbi" />
  </GetTasksAbi >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This is xamarin-forms v 3.0 known issue with visual studio 2017. I faced same issue on last week (ref : https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60293).

Fix : Install .NET framework 4.7.1. from Microsoft(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56116) and then restart your system.